# Sending a linspace vector to a function makes the vector all zeroes before the function starts

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, quad

I have been working on an algorithm for inverting Laplace transforms for some time in parallel processing (i.e. multiple Laplace functions in s-space being integrated simultaneously), *but I know for a fact that that the parallel processing is not the issue, as this method was implemented in an effort to resolve the problem*. But the problem remains, essentially my code spits this out over and over again:

```
Denominator too small. Exiting...
```

as well as various domain errors. I pinpointed the problem. Basically this:

```
for u in np.linspace(0.000001, 100, 1000000):
```

becomes all zeroes when `u` gets passed to any of the functions I want to integrate over. Not sure if it's the integration function:

```
x_1[num] = x * (-1) ** k * quad(f_p(num), -math.pi / 2, math.pi / 2, args=(u,))[0]
```

or the Laplace function `f_p` itself, but I've tried everything and I can't afford to waste more time spinning my wheels. I'd appreciate any help I can get. Here's the code you need to run the first Laplace inversion:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math
import multiprocessing as mp

gamma = 10
num = 1
k = 1
n = 0
epsilon = 10 ** -16
max_err = 10 ** -10
max_count = 1000000

x_iter = np.arange(1, 7)
x_1 = np.arange(1, 7)
x_2 = np.arange(1, 7)
x_3 = np.arange(1, 7)
denom = np.arange(1, 7)
AX = np.arange(1, 7)

a = gamma

def f_p1(omega, u):
    b = (omega + k * math.pi) / u

    f1 = a * (1 / (a ** 2 + (b + 1) ** 2) + 1 / (a ** 2 + (b - 1) ** 2))
    return f1 * math.cos(omega)

def f_p(num):
    if num == 1:
        return f_p1

def f_0(u, num):
    x = 2 * math.e ** (gamma * u) / (math.pi * u)
    return x * quad(f_p(num), 0, math.pi / 2, args=(u,))[0]

def f_u(u, num):
    k = 1
    x = 2 * math.e ** (gamma * u) / (math.pi * u)

    x_1[num] = x * (-1) ** k * quad(f_p(num), -math.pi / 2, math.pi / 2, args=(u,))[0]
    AX[num] = f_0(u, num)

    for j in range(max_count):
        if j > 0:
            x_1[num] = x_iter[num]

        k += 1
        x_2[num] = x * (-1) ** k * quad(f_p(num), -math.pi / 2, math.pi / 2, args=(u,))[0]
        k += 1
        x_3[num] = x * (-1) ** k * quad(f_p(num), -math.pi / 2, math.pi / 2, args=(u,))[0]

        denom[num] = (x_3[num] - x_2[num]) - (x_2[num] - x_1[num])

        if(abs(denom[num]) < epsilon):
            print("Denominator too small. Exiting...\n")
            break

        AX[num] = x_3[num] - ((x_3[num] - x_2[num]) ** 2) / denom[num]

        k += 1

        if(abs(AX[num] - x_3[num]) < max_err):
            print("Equation " + str(num) + "converges to " + str(AX[num]) + "\n")
            break

        x_iter[num] = AX[num]

        np.zeros(x_1)
        np.zeros(x_2)
        np.zeros(x_3)
        np.zeros(denom)
        np.zeros(AX)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('spawn')

    for u in np.linspace(0.000001, 100, max_count):

        p1 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 1))
        p2 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 2))
        p3 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 3))
        p4 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 4))
        p5 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 5))
        p6 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 6))

        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p3.start()
        p4.start()
        p5.start()
        p6.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        p3.join()
        p4.join()
        p5.join()
        p6.join()

    exit(0)
```

Comment: It's a very strange code. f_p function returns value only when n=1 and returns nothing in other cases, so, what are you integrating in a case n>1, is it nothing?

Comment: I think you should start from scratch, take one simple case and make it work, then you can add loops, processes and so on. Make work one simple integration first. For now it very hard to help you without knowing details about integration methods and so on.

Comment: The given code just errors out with `return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit), 
ValueError: invalid callable given`. That's because `f_p` returns `None` when not given `1`. Make sure the code reproduces the error you're seeing. Also, it'd be very useful to strip it of the multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a dumb question, I didn't really get how scipy's `quad` function worked and accidentally put `f_1(num)` in the place where I wanted the function to integrate with respect to `omega`. I also didn't put `k` in the arguments and added to instead of subtracting from `k` after my Aitken's acceleration (the part equal to `AX`).

I also had `np.zeros(AX)` at the end, which caused a bunch problems as well. Just messy in general.

It works now, and I removed the multiprocessing as the one guy suggested in order to plot these functions simultaneously. Didn't see much of a hit in performance at all, go figure.

*However*, it does not give the correct answer still for some reason, and I know its not the Laplace equation (`f_1`) being incorrect. I think it has to do with the way I iterated through the vector `u`... **If anyone knows how to integrate with respect to a variable and have another variable in the `args=` section that is not integrated, let me know!**

Here's a sample of how it looks now, for posterity. The original equation was built to do this to multiple equations, but I reduced it to 1 to keep it relatively brief. Try also playing around with the gamma parameter--it changes the way it converges, but not in the way I would like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps
import random
import datetime
from numba import jit

start = datetime.datetime.now()     # Record time start

# Initialize variables
gamma = 2    # Bromwich contour parameter
max_count = 1000   # Number of data points in x and y
epsilon = 10 ** -40     # Minimum number to divide by in Aitken's iteration
err = 10 ** -4    # Maximum difference in y to trigger comparison in closing()
max_err = 0.01    # Maximum difference in integrals computed in closing() to end iteration process

result = 0    # Store Aitken's iteration for closing() comparison
previous = 0     # Store iteration before Aitken's for closing() comparison

u, step = np.linspace(0.000005, 10, max_count, retstep=True)    # Initializing x values

y = np.empty([4, max_count])     # Initializing y values -- form is y[iteration in Aitken's][x value]

y_denom = np.empty([max_count])    # Initializing array to store Aitken's denominator values
x_iter = np.empty([max_count])    # Initializing array to store Aitken's iteration as starting point for next iteration

# Initialize plot
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.autoscale(enable=True)

def printer(k):    # Prints the iteration and y value at x = 10
    print(str(k) + "    " + str(y[3][max_count-1]) + "\n")

def plot1():    # Plots estimation 1 (blue) and actual equation 1 (red)
    ax.clear()
    line1, = ax.plot(u, y[3][:])
    ax.plot(u, np.sin(u), 'tab:red')
    return line1,

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p1(omega, u, k):      # Equation 1, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma

    f1 = a * (1 / (a ** 2 + (b + 1) ** 2) + 1 / (a ** 2 + (b - 1) ** 2)) * np.cos(omega)
    return f1

def closing(result, previous, k):    # Checks for convergence. If so, adds each term to f_0 and ends process
    if abs(result - previous) < max_err:
        diff = abs(result - previous)

        print("Equation converges to " + str(diff) + " with " + str(k) + " iterations." + "\n")

        for i in range(max_count):
            y[3][i] += f_0(i)
        return 1
    else:
        print("Equation has not yet converged.\n")
        return 0

def f_0(i):     # Initial integral in the series. Added at end after closing() convergence test
    x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
        f_p1, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]
    return x_0

def f_u(u):    # Main algorithm. Here, the summation integrals iterate
    k = 1   # Number of iterations

    for i in range(max_count):  # First overall series iteration (initial 1st)
        y[0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
            f_p1, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]

    for j in range(2000):   # Iteration loop. Goes until closing() or k = ~2000 (~8000 total iterations)
        if j > 0:
            for i in range(max_count):  # Sets the first iteration (out of 3 for Aitken's) equal to the previous Aitken's or the first iteration if j = 0 (1st)
                y[0][i] = x_iter[i]
            else:
                k += 1

        for i in range(max_count):  # Second iteration for Aitken's (2nd)
            y[1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p1, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]

        k += 1

        for i in range(max_count):  # Third iteration for Aitken's (3rd)
            y[2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p1, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]

        for i in range(max_count):  # Aitken's delta-squared method iteration using the previous 3 (4th)
            y_denom[i] = (y[2][i] - y[1][i]) - (y[1][i] - y[0][i])

            if abs(y_denom[i]) < epsilon:
                print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                return 9

            y[3][i] = y[2][i] - ((y[2][i] - y[1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[i]

        k -= 1
        printer(k)
        plot1()

        rand = random.randrange(0, max_count)   # Setting random number for x value

        # Comparison between y at random x in Aitken's vs the previous iteration. If close enough, triggers closing()
        if abs(y[3][rand] - y[2][rand]) < err:
            result = simps(y[3][:], u, dx=step)   #Integrates Aitken's iteration (4th)
            previous = simps(y[2][:], u, dx=step)    #Integrates integration before Aitken's (3rd)
            c1 = closing(result, previous, k)
            if c1 == 1:
                return 0

        for i in range(max_count):  # Setting current Aitken's iteration to first iteration
            x_iter[i] = y[3][i]
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run the algorithm and plot
    f_u(u)

    plot1()

    end = datetime.datetime.now()   # Record time end

    print("Runtime: " + str(end - start))

    # Plots final result
    plt.show()

    exit(0)
```